# Possible dimension of column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I tried to solve the following problem. I would like to verify if my solution is correct.

> Let $A$ be a $4\times 5$ matrix with real entries. For each case
> below, find all possible dimensions of a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$
> spanned by the first, second, and third column vector of $A$.
>
> (1) When we can apply row operation(s) on $A$ and obtain
>
> $B = \begin{pmatrix}1& 3 & 0 & 1 &
> 0\\0&0&1&-2&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\ \end{pmatrix} \tag*{}$
>
> (2) When we can apply row operation(s) and column operation(s) on $A$
> and obtain
>
> $C = \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\ \end{pmatrix} \tag*{}$
> *Source(Japanese): https://web.archive.org/web/20130211080104/http://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/kyoumu/MA2006.pdf , Translation to English done by myself.*

**My Attempt**

We denote a subspace spanned by vectors $\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ by $\mathrm{span}\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$.

(1)

Since row operations can be expressed by multiplying an invertible matrix from left, there exists a $4\times 4$ invertible matrix $P$ such that $PA=B$.

Now, write $A$ in terms of column vectors: $A=(a_1,\cdots a_5)$ where $a_i$ is the $i$-th column vector of $A$. Then, $PA = (Pa_1,\cdots Pa_5)$. Therefore, $i$-th column vector of $B$ is $Pa_i$.

It is easy to see that $\dim\mathrm{span}\{Pa_1,Pa_2,Pa_3\} = 2$.

What we would like to find is $\dim\mathrm{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, and this is equal to $\mathrm{rank}(A')$ where $A'=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, since rank is equal to the dimension of the column space. Now, since $P$ is invertible, we have $\mathrm{rank}(PA')=\mathrm{rank}(A')$. Moreover, $PA'= (Pa_1,Pa_2,Pa_3)$, so $\mathrm{rank}(PA')=\dim\mathrm{span}\{Pa_1,Pa_2,Pa_3\} = 2$.

Therefore, $\dim\mathrm{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}=2$ is the only possible dimension.

(2)
Since column operation can be expressed as multiplying an invertible matrix from right, there exists invertible matrices $P,Q$ such that $PAQ=C$.

As we have seen in (1), we have $\dim\mathrm{span}\{Pa_1,Pa_2,Pa_3\}=\dim\mathrm{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, so WLOG we can assume $P=I$(identity matrix).

By definition, $\dim\mathrm{span}\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\leq 3$. $\dim = 3$ is possible in the case $A=C$. $\dim = 2$ is also possible in the case $A=(e_1,0,e_3,e_4,e_2)$ where $e_i$ is a vector with $i$-th element $1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now, if $\dim \leq 1$, then the maximal number of indepent column vectors of $A$ is at most $3$. However, $\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(C)=4$ since $P,Q$ are invertible. This is contradiction.

Therefore, the possible dimensions are $2,3$.

Comment: You're not wrong but it seems excessive to do it this way. Do you know anything about the pivots of a matrix?

Comment: @CyclotomicField No, but I am open to learn a new way.

Comment: In reduced form like this the pivots are the first non-zero entries in each row. The number of pivots is the dimension of the space spanned by those columns or rows. So you can just see the first three columns have two pivots in the first matrix, thus spans a two dimensional space. The second matrix has three pivots in the first three columns and so spans a three dimensional space. You are well prepared to prove this statement if you'd like to give it a try.